# Grammar in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

So I have take inspiration from the DOT.g4 grammar in this github repository [grammars-v4/dot/DOT.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dot/DOT.g4). Tht's why I have as well a DOT file to parse.

This is a possible structure of my DOT file:

```
digraph G {
 rankdir=LR
  label="\n[Büchi]"
  labelloc="t"
  node [shape="circle"]
  I [label="", style=invis, width=0]
  I -> 34
  0 [label="0", peripheries=2]
  0 -> 0 [label="!v_0"]
  1 [label="1", peripheries=2]
  1 -> 1 [label="!v_2 & !v_5"]
  2 [label="2"]
  2 -> 1 [label="v_0 & v_1 > 5 & !v_2 & v_3 < 8 & !v_5"]
  3 [label="3"]
  3 -> 1 [label="v_0 & v_1 > 5 & !v_2 & v_3 < 8 & !v_5"]
  4 [label="4"]
  4 -> 1 [label="v_1 > 5 & !v_2 & v_3 < 8 & !v_5"]
  5 [label="5"]
  5 -> 1 [label="v_0 & v_1 > 5 & !v_2 & v_3 < 8 & !v_5"]
}
```

And Here my grammar.g4 file that I have modified from the link above:

```
parse: nba| EOF;
nba: STRICT? ( GRAPH | DIGRAPH ) ( initialId? ) '{' stmtList '}';
stmtList : ( stmt ';'? )* ;
stmt: nodeStmt| edgeStmt| attrStmt | initialId '=' initialId;
attrStmt: ( GRAPH | NODE | EDGE )  '[' a_list? ']';
a_list: ( initialId ( '=' initialId  )? ','? )+;
edgeStmt: (node_id) edgeRHS label ',' a_list? ']';
label: ('[' LABEL '=' '"' (id)+ '"' );
edgeRHS: ( edgeop ( node_id ) )+;
edgeop: '->';
nodeStmt: node_id label? ',' a_list? ']';
node_id: initialId ;
id: ID | SPACE | DIGIT | LETTER | SYMBOL | STRING ;
initialId : STRING | LETTER | DIGIT;
```

And here the lexar rules:

```
GRAPH: [Gg] [Rr] [Aa] [Pp] [Hh];
DIGRAPH: [Dd] [Ii] [Gg] [Rr] [Aa] [Pp] [Hh];
NODE: [Nn] [Oo] [Dd] [Ee];
EDGE: [Ee] [Dd] [Gg] [Ee];
LABEL: [Ll] [Aa] [Bb] [Ee] [Ll];
/** "a numeral [-]?(.[0-9]+ | [0-9]+(.[0-9]*)? )" */
NUMBER: '-'? ( '.' DIGIT+ | DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT* )? );
DIGIT: [0-9];
/** "any double-quoted string ("...") possibly containing escaped quotes" */
STRING: '"' ( '\\"' | . )*? '"';
/** "Any string of alphabetic ([a-zA-Z\200-\377]) characters, underscores
 *  ('_') or digits ([0-9]), not beginning with a digit"
*/
ID: LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT )*;
SPACE: '" "';
LETTER: [a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF_];
SYMBOL: '<'| '>'| '&'| 'U'| '!';
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;
LINE_COMMENT: '//' .*? '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
/** "a '#' character is considered a line output from a C preprocessor */
PREPROC: '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
/*whitespace are ignored from the constructor*/
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

I clicked on the ANTLR Recognizer section that create itself the files in java and the tokens to interpreter the grammars. Now I have to construct a parser in which I overrride some methods to match my code in Java with the java files created by ANTLR4. But first I want to understand if my grammar for that kind of DOT is correct. How can I verify that?

Comment: Your grammar doesn't work. Use the "grun" command (aka `java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig`) as Mike explains below to test. Some other notes: (1) Place the parser and lexer rules in one file. (2) It doesn't parse your input because "initialId" doesn't have "ID" or just "id" on the right-hand side. (3) "LETTER" is always hidden by "ID" (it comes before "LETTER" in the list of rules), so it's a completely useless rule/symbol, and will never be recognized by the lexer.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "I clicked on the ANTLR Recognizer"... sounds like you're using some sort of IDE with a plugin or another ANTLR tool.  Use use VS Code and IntelliJ with plugins, but neither has an "ANTLR Recognizer" section (that I can see).  So the following assumes using the command line.  It's simple command line stuff and definitely worth learning early on when using ANTLR.  (Both of the plugins I use also give the ability to view the token stream and parse tree from within the plugin though)

I you follow the "QuickStart" at [www.antlr.org](https://www.antlr.org), you'll have created the `grun` alias that's useful for just this purpose.

(Assuming your grammar name is `DOT`)

To dump out your token stream (the result of all you lexer rules)

```
grun DOT tokens -tokens
```

To verify that you're parsing input correctly:

```
grun DOT parse -gui
```

or

```
grun DOT parse -tree
```

BTW, it's rather unlikely that you'll need to override the parser class.  First take a look into Visitor and Listeners.